# Shell script sort list

Tags: algorithm, bash, sorting

I have a list with the following content:

```
VIP NAME DATE  ARRIVE_TIME FLIGHT_TIME

1  USER1 11-02    20.00    21.00
3  USER2 11-02    20.45    21.45
4  USER2 11-03    20.00    21.30
2  USER1 11-04    17.20    19.10
```

I want to sort this and similar lists with a shell script. The result should be a new list with lines that do not collide. VIP 1 is most important, if any VIP with a bigger number has `ARRIVE_TIME` before `FLIGHT_TIME` for VIP 1 on the same date this line should be removed, so the `VIP` number should be used to decide which lines to keep if the `ARRIVE_TIME`, `FLIGHT_TIME` and `DATE` collide. Similarly, VIP 2 is more important than VIP 3 and so on.

This is pretty advanced, and I am totally empty for ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Is this best done in a shell script? Why not use Perl?

Comment: This would also be okay, but i have more expirence with bash scriptingh than with Perl

Comment: @j smith perl is perfect for this sort of thing. Depending on the size of the file you can just pull the whole file in and sort it. This kind of the is on of the reasons perl exists. I can post an answer in perl if you want. Just say the word.

Comment: @ Elizabeth Buckwalter, the list will contain max 10 lines so it's not very big. I would be very happy the see the perl version to solve this, if you have the possibility to post it.

Comment: Collidate?  Do you mean 'collide'?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler yes i did mean collide, collidate may be some sort of mix between English and my native language =)

Comment: If you need help with learning Perl, I can recommend a good book or two. :)

Comment: One way you could frame the question better would be to include more sample data and an example of what the final result should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started:

- I'm ignoring the header line. You can get rid of it using `head` or skip it in the `for` loop.
- Sort the flights by date, arrival, departure and vip number - having the vip number as a sort key simplifies the logic later.
- I'm saving the result in an array, but you could redirect it to a temporary file and read it in a line at a time with a `while read line; do ...; done <tempfile` loop.
- I'm using indirection to make things more readable (naming the fields instead of using array indices directly - the exclamation point means indirection here instead of "not")
- For each line in the result that occurs on the same date as the most recently **printed** line, compare its arrival time to the previous flight's departure time
- Echo the lines that are appropriate.
- save the date and departure time for later comparison.
- You should adjust the `<` comparison to be `<=` if that works better for your data.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
flights=($(sort -k3,3 -k4,4n -k5,5n -k1,1n flights ))
IFS="$saveIFS"

date=fields[2]
arrive=fields[3]
depart=fields[4]

for line in "${flights[@]}"
do
    fields=($line)
    if [[ ${!date} == $prevdate && ${!arrive} < $prevdep ]]
    then
        echo "deleted: $line"    # or you could do something else here
    else
        echo $line
        prevdep=${!depart}
        prevdate=${!date}
    fi
done
```

Comment: This seems interesting, i need to take a closer look at this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unix sort command to do this:

There's an example of how to set primary and secondary keys etc:

[Example](http://xlonline.org.uk/Legacy%20Materials/Final%20Ouputs/Preview%20files/DH3A%2034%20Multi%20User%20Operating%20Systems/LO2_ManipulateData_Part_3_/page_13.htm)

The uniq command is what you need to remove dupes.

Comment: This misses the point in that the situation for identifying a duplicate is extremely non-trivial.  The question is badly framed (possibly because of unrealistic data and/or criteria), but the 'duplicates' are not simple duplicate lines; there is a different VIP number, for example, but the second is less important than the first and therefore gets bumped.

Comment: I don't know how to frame the question any better, but i think that it is somehow clear what i want to do.